# syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input, but can't find any open tags

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I've been looking at this for a while now, and I can't seem to find any open tags that ought to be closed. But I keep getting a rails syntax error, that says "expecting end-of-input". I've looked at all the tags and even broken it down on a sheet of paper, but I can't find any tag that should be closed which would cause this error. Is there something else that is wrong here, or did I miss something that is super simple?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <%= link_to "Professor Reviews", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <% # if user_signed_in? %>
              <li><%= link_to "All Professors", professors_path %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "New Professor", new_professor_path, class: "active" %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Account", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
            <!-- <%  else %>
              <li><%= link_to "All Professors", professors_path %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, class: "active" %> </li>
              <li><%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path, class: "active" %></li>
            <% end %> -->
          </ul>
          <%= form_tag search_professors_path, method: :get, class: "navbar-form navbar-right", role: "Search" do %>
          <p>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control" %>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
          </p>
          <% end %>


        </div>
      </div>

    </nav>
```

Comment: to comment rails tag use # can see your <%  else %> and <% end %> not commented properly

Comment: Try commenting `<%  else %>` and `<% end %>` with `#`  since your `<% # if user_signed_in? %>` condition is commented.

Comment: Thank you everyone sorry I'm new to Rails.

Comment: It's not so obvious I think, anyway, now you know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html commented code is run..

So the error is in `<!-- <% else %>` because the `<% # if ...` is not run.